# Which of these sentences are correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which of these sentences are correct?

- 1. I saw an asleep person.
- 2. I saw some asleep people.
- 3. I saw some asleep persons.
- 4. I saw some people asleep.

This is a question in my English book that I couldn't get my head around it, it would be great if someone could give me an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"asleep is not used before a noun"

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/asleep

(4) is correct; the others need *sleeping* instead.